# AMP Email - Works in Playground page but breaks inside gmail

Tags: amp-html, amp-email

I have an AMP email template with some custom actions and bindings based on an XHR. The code works perfectly fine in the playground link (https://amp.gmail.dev/playground/). However when loaded in gmail, the same does not work. Some of the bindings (AMP.setstate) does not happen. Is AMPEmail still in beta and should we expect some bugs?

Comment: Have you performed the [needed action](https://developers.google.com/gmail/ampemail/testing-dynamic-email) "Navigate to **Gmail Settings** > **General** > **Dynamic email** and click **Dynamic email development**"?. "This opens a dialog where you can whitelist email addresses that can send you dynamic emails for testing purposes".

Comment: any other ideas, seems very buggy

Answer (score 2):

Its a known problem. Unfortunately not everything that works in the Playground will automatically work in the Gmail yet. It looks like Gmail has a slightly different engine and some components do not work as expected. You can confirm this with AMP Email team, by contacting them directly - https://developers.google.com/gmail/ampemail/support

Answer (score 0):

Could you check that you have enabled 'Dynamic email' in your GMAIL settings?

Comment: Enabled the dev settings. and have had lots of similar issues, and was even down for a day two last week (the email playground).

Comment: Im now trying to get my tabbed area to work in gmail as it works in playground

Comment: amp-selector styling not wokring in gmail but given as example for tabs area to work. If i style using classes it works but cant use :selected unfortunately which is what i need:

e.g. 

amp-selector[role=tablist].tabs-with-flex [role=tabpanel]

wont work in gmail